# Would these be considered "commercial use"?

Tags: images, legal, licensing

From the Creative Commons website:

> A commercial use is one primarily intended for commercial advantage or
>   monetary compensation.

Would it be considered commercial use if an image was used in a blog post that provides valuable info to readers and isn't trying to sell something (e.g. a guide, how-to, etc.)? The blog would be part of a website that does offer services though, but there's nothing you can purchase on the website.

Comment: CC licenses are never terribly clear, unfortunately. Best to ask the owner of the image directly. In general, though, I'd say this leans towards commercial--as in the end the blog is intended to promote something.

Comment: Everything that makes you money, even if only to cover the costs is considered commercial. You literally have to give it away for free in order not to be commercial. If for example there is also advertisement on the website it might already have a commercial character. IANAL of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commercial use means that the image is used directly in the marketing and promotion of a product that results in monetary gain. Otherwise, you are fine as long as you don't claim ownership of the image either explicitly or implied.